# Is it possible to keystroke special characters in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, text, internationalization

### The Bug:

For certain special characters and symbols, AppleScript will fail to `keystroke` the actual character, and will instead simply type the letter `a`.

---

### An Example:

The following AppleScript code:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "² ³ é ½ ₭"
```

types the following string of text (no matter what application that I am in):

```
a a a a a
```

---

### A Workaround:

One can *effectively* "type" the text by placing the special characters on the clipboard, and then pasting the clipboard, like so:

```
set the clipboard to "² ³ é ½ ₭"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

I avoid using the above method to put text on the clipboard in AppleScript, because it necessarily converts the clipboard to rich text, in the process.

I prefer to employ [the method provided here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286381/applescript-bug-when-placing-plain-text-on-the-clipboard-the-text-is-always-co/286391#286391), to ensure that plain text is placed on the clipboard. But, this method converts special characters to mojibake.

For example, using the same string as above, this method puts the following text on the clipboard:

```
¬≤ ¬≥ √© ¬Ω ‚Ç≠
```

You can manually account for this issue, however, by adding a [`replace_chars`](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html) statement for each special character.

---

### The Question:

Is there a way to type special characters via AppleScript, *without* having to involve the clipboard?

For example, is there some way that I can add the desired special characters to a "bank" or system file somewhere, so that the `System Events` application is familiar with them?

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible with **CoreGraphics** (`CGEventPost`), it's a **C** API (it doesn't work in a Cocoa-AppleScript), but it's possible to call an executable from an AppleScript.

---

Here is the method to create the executable with Xcode (Version 8.3.3):

You can do it yourself (you can download **Xcode** from the **App Store**), or ask a trusted person to create the executable.

**1-** Open Xcode, select menu "**File**" --> "**New**" --> "**Project**..."
[image]

---

**2-** Select **macOS** and **Command Line Tool**, click on the "**Next**" button.
[image]

---

**3-** Name it `TypeCharacters`, select **Objective-C** as Language, click on the "**Next**" button.
[image]

---

**4-** Save the project to the desired folder.

---

**5-** In the window of Xcode, select the `main.m` icon, clear the text in the window and paste one of these two codes:

The code need a loop because of a bug, the `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString()` method truncates a string which exceeds twenty characters, or it's a limit (not documented).

This code use a loop to type a list of characters at each iteration, the list can contain one to twenty characters. (It's fast, 1 seconds to type 2400 characters in a TextEdit's document on my computer.)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (argc > 1) {
            NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
            NSUInteger len = [theString length];
            NSUInteger n, i = 0;
            CGEventRef keyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0, true);
            unichar uChars[20];
            while (i < len) {
                n = i + 20;
                if (n>len){n=len;}
                [theString getCharacters:uChars range:NSMakeRange(i, n-i)];
                CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEvent, n-i, uChars);
                CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent); // key down
                CGEventSetType(keyEvent, kCGEventKeyUp);
                CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent); // key up (type 20 characters maximum)
                CGEventSetType(keyEvent, kCGEventKeyDown);
                i = n;
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.004]; // wait 4/1000 of second, 0.002 it's OK on my computer, I use 0.004 to be safe, increase it If you still have issues
            }
            CFRelease(keyEvent);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code use a loop to type one character at each iteration (It's slower than the first code).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (argc > 1) {
            NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
            UniChar uChar;
            CGEventRef keyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < [theString length]; i++)
            {
                uChar = [theString characterAtIndex:i];
                CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEvent, 1, &uChar);
                CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent); // key down
                CGEventSetType(keyEvent, kCGEventKeyUp);
                CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent); // key up (type the character)
                CGEventSetType(keyEvent, kCGEventKeyDown);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.001]; // wait 1/1000 of second, no need of this line on my computer, I use 0.001 to be safe, increase it If you still have issues
            }
            CFRelease(keyEvent);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** : This code works on **macOS Sierra** and should work on **El Capitan**, but not on an older **OS**.

[image]

---

**6-** Select menu "**Product**" --> "**Build**".

---

**7-** Select the `TypeCharacters` icon in the **Product** folder, right-click and select the "**Show in Finder**" menu in the contextual menu.

[image]

---

**8-** From the Finder, move the "**TypeCharacters**" file to the desired folder, quit **Xcode**, that's all.

---

From an **AppleScript**, call the executable, like this

```
set myString to "ùéèà ² ³ é ½ ₭ "
do shell script "'/full path/of/TypeCharacters' " & quoted form of myString
```

Comment: Incredible answer. This solution works flawlessly on OS X 10.11.6 as well. I couldn't dream of a better solution. I also appreciate the detailed screenshots. Many, many thanks!!!

Comment: I have discovered a bug: If the length of `myString` exceeds 20 characters, then the string will be truncated. That is, any text that follows the twentieth character will not be typed. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Now ,I use a loop to type each character, (tested with a string of 2000 or more characters), I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Your new solution has solved the problem. Thanks! Side note, you removed the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` line from your code in your edit, but this line is still necessary for a successful build. I know that this line of code is there by default, but some ambiguity exists because your instructions say to *"clear the text in the window."*

Comment: I think the new solution has a new bug. Every so often, the typed text will be missing a character or change the order of the text. This occurs no matter the string length. Here is a real example: The string that the TypeCharacters file was given was `= 278,932` but the following string was typed:  `=2 78,93`.

Comment: No bugs here. Maybe  a (substitution, a transformation or the correct spelling automatically) in the foreground application. Check the text replacement in the "System Preferences". Otherwise, use the debug code (in my answer).

Comment: Maybe (**during heavy CPU load**) the code need a small delay between each **KeyDown**.
Try that: add this line at the end of the loop `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.02]; //  wait 2/100 of second, increase it If you still have issues.`. I updated the code in my answer.

I append another code in my answer (this code can type **20 characters** on each iteration instead of one character, try it.

Comment: Hmm. It is definitely not a text substitution/transformation issue. Also, the issue occurs even when no other application is open, so it's not CPU-load-dependent (and it occurs in any given application, from TextEdit to Google Chrome). I reset my NVRAM and SMC; the issue persists. Maybe it's an El Capitan issue? BTW, I use an Early-2013 Retina MacBook Pro, so perhaps my computer is simply getting old and sluggish.

Comment: Whatever is responsible for causing the issue, either of your two new solutions seem to have entirely stopped the issue. Here are GIFs that show the outcomes on my computer: If I use [the 1st code block](http://i.imgur.com/weMNZTS.gif) in your current answer. If I use [the debug code](http://i.imgur.com/TkZdmC5.gif). If I use [the 3rd code block](http://i.imgur.com/GI1fAcY.gif) (which I modified with a shorter delay).

Comment: I am glad  that your issue has been resolved.
On my computer: typing one character at each iteration doesn't need the `sleepForTimeInterval:` method, but this is necessary for typing a list of characters at each iteration (If the string contains more than twenty characters of course). I updated my answer (cleaning).

Comment: I have realized that this `TypeCharacters` script is not able to type newline characters. Also, if the string contains a newline, then it will not type the string at all. Do you know how to preserve newlines in the typed text? Thank you.

Comment: Since this actually simulates pressing keys, if you press a modifier key during this can bad things happen?

Comment: @BallpointBen Apparently not! I’ve just tested by having it type a “p” into Xcode while I was holding the command key. The print dialog did not show up. I did get a system beep sound though. (Also tested with uppercase “P”.)

Answer (score 6):

A workaround (with the clipboard):

**1 -** You can use a cocoa method from a shell:

```
set tString to "² ³ é ½ ₭"
my stringToClipboard(tString)
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down

on stringToClipboard(t1)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c 'import sys;from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSPasteboardTypeString; cb=NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard();cb.declareTypes_owner_([NSPasteboardTypeString], None);cb.setString_forType_(sys.argv[1].decode(\"utf8\"), NSPasteboardTypeString)' " & quoted form of t1
end stringToClipboard
```

---

**2 -** Or a Cocoa-AppleScript Applet:

```
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions
set tString to "² ³ é ½ ₭"
my stringToClipboard(tString)
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down

on stringToClipboard(t1)
    set ca to current application
    set cb to ca's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
    cb's declareTypes:{ca's NSPasteboardTypeString} owner:(missing value)
    cb's setString:t1 forType:(ca's NSPasteboardTypeString)
end stringToClipboard
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to `keystroke` a character, that character needs to be mapped to an actual key on your selected keyboard.

For instance, I can `keystroke` **é** and **²** just fine, because I’m using the **French — PC** keyboard layout. However a standard American QWERTY keyboard does not feature those keys and will be unable to `keystroke` them.

Answer (score 2):

You can define all your special character sets as variables, like this

```
on specialKeys(input)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke input
    end tell
end specialKeys


set characterSet1 to "²³é½₭ "
set characterSet2 to "¬≥ "
set characterSet3 to "√© "
set characterSet4 to "¬Ω "
set characterSet5 to "‚Ç≠ "
set characterSet6 to characterSet1 & characterSet2 & characterSet3 & characterSet4 & characterSet5

specialKeys(characterSet1)
-- ² ³ é ½ ₭ is the result from calling specialKeys(characterSet1) After adding the text replacement for “a a a a a” in my keyboard preferences
```

Some special characters keystroke correctly when you set them as variables. Any of the special characters that you set as variables that do not keystroke properly, you can add “text replacements” in the system preferences for your keyboard.

Be sure to select all of the items and drag them to your desktop or wherever.  This will create a .plist file which will be a backup of your original settings.  You can drag this file back at anytime.

[image]

[image]

Then in ScriptEditor, make sure you have text replacements enabled in the “substitutions” sub menu of the edit menu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The *"Text Replacement"* workaround works as desired in the majority of OS X applications (e.g., TextEdit, Notes, Script Editor, etc.), but I was hoping for a solution that would work in *every* text field in any application. Asking for a lot, I know! I still think that this is a very clever solution, so +1. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can input non-ASCII characters with the clipboard:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set textBuffer to "² ³ é ½ ₭"
    repeat with i from 1 to count characters of textBuffer
        set the clipboard to (character i of textBuffer)
        delay 0.05
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end repeat
end tell
```